# Issue with exporting asynchronous member

Tags: typescript, async-await

So, I'm having an issue where, when exporting an asynchronous function and importing other members of this file that are not asynchronous they are undefined.

Here is how it is set up:

**functions.ts**

```
export function getEnvironmentVariable(variable: string, defaultVal: string): string {
    return process.env[variable] ?? defaultVal;
}

export async function handleDiscordToGameChat(member: GuildMember, chatChannel: string, content: string): Promise<{
    ok: boolean;
    response: string
}> {
    const currentAuth = getAuthLvlFromMember(member);
    const apiKey = getApiKeyForAuth(currentAuth);

    if (!apiKey || currentAuth.rank < hsgRoleMap.GS.rank) {
        return {
            ok: false,
            response: 'Insufficient permissions.'
        };
    }

    const req = await fetch(`http://${API_ENDPOINT}/${isLocalServer() ? 'hsg-server' : 'hsg-rp'}/sendMessageToGame`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'token': apiKey
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            content,
            chatChannel,
            adminDets: {
                name: member.user.tag,
                authLvl: currentAuth.acronym
            }
        })
    });

    const data = await req.json();

    if (!data.ok) {
        return {
            ok: false,
            response: data.response
        };
    }

    return {
        ok: true,
        response: 'Successfully sent message.'
    };
}
```

When trying to access exported member `getEnvironmentVariable` in another file (`config.ts`) through:

```
import { getEnvironmentVariable } from './utils/functions';

console.log(typeof getEnvironmentVariable); // undefined
```

Though, after removing the export of the asynchronous member, it returns function. Should I be keeping all asynchronous exports in a separate file or so?

EDIT: Forgot to add: My IDE identifies the exported member as a function and does not through any compilation errors, it is only at runtime which is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

It might an issue with your import statement's path. May be your code is unable to find the file that exports your `getEnvironmentVariable` function.

Comment: I should've added the fact that my IDE identifies the exported member as a function and even allows me to go to the definition of the function.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for better understanding